# How to use sed or awk to replace after equal symbol following space with symbol ^^ as delimiter

Tags: awk, sed

Input file format

```
Text test=123 session_id=12356 Browser_ID=23466 url=http://test.com/Add-JARs-to-Project-Build-Paths-in-Eclipse-%28Java%29
Text test=213 session_id=23561 Browser_ID=24661 url=http://test.com/
```

Expected output format

```
Text test1=123^^session_id=12356^^Browser_ID=23466^^url=http://test.com/Add-JARs-to-Project-Build-Paths-in-Eclipse-%28Java%29
Text test2=213^^session_id=23561^^Browser_ID=24661^^url=http://test.com/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should do...

```
sed -E 's/(=[^= ]+) /\1^^/g' file
```

Comment: This doen't append ascending numbers to `test`

Comment: Yes, I see...  An undocumented specification!

Answer (score 0):

If you want (GNU)-awk:

```
awk -v OFS="^^" '{ gsub(/test/,"test"NR); $1=$1" "$2; for(i=3; i<=NF; i++)$(i-1)=$i; NF--;  print }' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Always a case of knowing the data well, but assuming we are just replacing from second space till the end, you could do:

```
sed ':a s/ /^^/2;ta' file
```